# Plotting data from csv using matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7, matplotlib

I am trying to follow a tutorial on youtube, now in the tutorial they plot some standard text files using matplotlib.pyplot, I can achieve this easy enough, however I am now trying to perform the same thing using some csvs I have of real data.

The code I am using is  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import csv
    #import numpy as np

```
with open(r"Example RFI regression axis\Delta RFI.csv") as x, open(r"Example RFI regression axis\strikerate.csv") as y:
    readx = csv.reader(x)
    ready = csv.reader(y)

    plt.plot(readx,ready)

    plt.title ('Test graph')
    plt.xlabel('x axis')
    plt.ylabel('y axis')

    plt.show()
```

The traceback I receive is long

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\V4 code snippets\matplotlib_test.py", line 11, in <module>
    plt.plot(readx,ready)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2832, in plot
    ret = ax.plot(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 3997, in plot
    self.add_line(line)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 1507, in add_line
    self._update_line_limits(line)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 1516, in _update_line_limits
    path = line.get_path()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\lines.py", line 677, in get_path
    self.recache()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\lines.py", line 401, in recache
    x = np.asarray(xconv, np.float_)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 320, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

Please advise what I need to do, I realise this is probably very easy to most seasoned coders. Kind regards SMNALLY

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`csv.reader()` returns strings (technically, `.next()`method of reader object returns lists of strings). Without converting them to `float` or `int`, you won't be able to `plt.plot()` them.

To save the trouble of converting, I suggest using `genfromtxt()` from `numpy`. (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html)

For example, there are two files: 
data1.csv:

```
data1
2
3
4
3
6
6
4
```

and data2.csv:

```
data2
92
73
64
53
16
26
74
```

Both of them have one line of header. We can do:

```
import numpy as np
data1=np.genfromtxt('data1.csv', skip_header=1) #suppose it is in the current working directory
data2=np.genfromtxt('data2.csv', skip_header=1)
plt.plot(data1, data2,'o-')
```

and the result:

[image]

Comment: Hi CT Zhu, thanks for the reply, I feel this could well be the answer I am looking for. Is there any chance of providing more detail of how to do this for the example provided? Many thanks SMNALLY

Comment: You are welcome. And an example was just added. Let me know if the example fits the structure of your `csv` files.

Comment: Not normal Stackoverflow etiquette but.. I think i love you... many thanks  :)

Comment: Testing... testing...testing...perfect :) :) :) Will be all over this now. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: my only question is what does the `'o-'` do ?

Comment: It is shorthand for `marker='o', linestyle='-'`: use filled circles for data points and solid line to connect them.

Comment: Ahh i will probably bump intot his as i progress through the tutorial, thanks for the heads up tho :)